# Heap Snapshot shows HTMLDocument having an IdleTask leaking memory?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, gruntjs

I've got a NodeJS app which seems to be leaking memory (like a lot), I've been looking at heap snapshots and comparing them for hours but I can't find what's going wrong...

After the leakage, about 80% of the objects look like this:
[image: The leakage has to do with Idle Requests]

I can't find out why these aren't garbage collected or even created in the first place.

Is it because of the `<symbol> in global`? If so, what does this mean?
Has this something to do with grunt, since it's V8IdleRequestCallback?

Comment: I dont know but when i get `HTMLDocument` coming up in the heap snapshot it seems issues with my webapp. It seems to (maybe) be leaking memory somehow holding references to new documents on iframe reloads and I cannot figure out how to track it down or eliminate the GC roots (yet)